# Haskell IO execution order

Tags: haskell, io, order-of-execution

I've got the following code:

```
import Control.Monad (unless)
import System.IO (isEOF, hFlush, stdout)

main :: IO ()
main = unlessFinished $ do
        putStr "$ "
        hFlush stdout
        getLine >>= putStrLn
        main
    where
    unlessFinished action = isEOF >>= flip unless action
```

When I compile and run this code, it displays a cursor at the begining of the blank line and only after I hit [Enter] it outputs `$` and whatever I'd written.

It would seem that `getLine` gets called before `putStr "$ "` even though `IO` monad guarantees that it's actions are called in the order they're sequenced in the code (or so I understand what is written [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/IO_inside)). So why it doesn't work correctly?

Comment: By the way, I actually didn't believe you until I tried running the code myself. Then I actually said "whaaaaa...?!" aloud in my cubicle. Nice work distilling your question into such a nice, digestible, surprising form!

Comment: Thank you. It was surprising to me as well. Actually I was beginning to believe that it's not Haskell's "fault" after all, but some other shell/terminal/OS pitfall that I didn't know about before. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, the `putStr` and `hFlush` actions *are* being executed before the `getLine` action -- however, `isEOF` is being executed before either, and it doesn't return until it knows whether the input is `EOF` or not, that is, until you enter a line. You might consider moving the `isEOF` to right before the `getLine`, like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStr "$ "
    hFlush stdout
    unlessFinished $ do
        getLine >>= putStrLn
        main
    where
    unlessFinished action = isEOF >>= flip unless action
```

Comment: Strikingly simple explanation! I'm already wondering how couldn't I think of it myself. I turns out, that Haskell still has more pitfalls for me than I expected. Thanks a lot. :)